# USB Drive not recognized by Win7 but Win10 Ok

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb-storage

I have a WD 1TB Passport USB drive. On my Win10 machine, it opens just file and shows up under as a drive under "Computer". On Win7 it doesnt: when I plug it in, I only see "WD Unlocker", an 8MB UDF volume. I have seen solutions that say I should reformat the drive but it contains many hundreds of GB that I *really* don't want to recreate.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not have any more Windows 7 systems. If you really do not want to re-create, consider another USB drive and copy from old to new. Then try the new drive on the Windows 7 machine. That is all I can think of short of re-creating.

Comment: Can you open Disk Manager and check your drive there? Looks like your main partition does not have assigned a letter but the "recovery" one is the one showing up. If you assign a letter to your main partition it should work fine.

Comment: What I tried, SUCCESSFULLY: (1) On another Win7 machine. (2) Another USB drive.

Comment: I tried disk manager. The drive DID show up and HAD a drive letter (D:). I found that I COULD access the files on it from the command prompt, but still no show under "Computer". This was good enough for my needs but still a mystery.

Comment: BTW, a Google answer said that the WD Unlocker drive was a "Virtual CD" created by the drive firmware. Unverified, but it fits what I see. I tried deleting the Unlocker EXE using Unbuntu but that failed.